# 12.10 sound resumes only after Suspend

Tags: sound, 12.10

I installed the 12.10 yesterday and like 12.04 there was no sound, I have an ACER 4830 TG. I noticed that the HDMI output is working fine, but Speaker or Headphone isn't working.

So I did the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and still couldn't get the sound.

Then I found the temp fix for this issue which is to Suspend the machine completely and resume. However, after restart the same thing happens.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this worked for me.

Use terminal to open:

```
sudo gedit nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Then paste the following line at the end of the file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=acer
sudo alsa force-reload
```

For more information check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto